# Problems in playing frame by frame animations in iOS UIImageView

Tags: ios, frame, nstimer, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to show an animation in my iOS app but because of some reasons I don't wanna use default iOS UIAnimation like :

`ImageView.animationImages = arrayOfImages;`

`[ImageView startAnimating];`

I scheduled a timer which calls AnimationTick method each 0.015 sec and here's the implementation of that method :

```
-(void)animationTick{
if ( self.frameNumber > 0 && self.frameNumber < 19 )
{
    self.c2cAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 700, 1000)];
    self.c2cAnimation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L6_anim_%d.png",self.frameNumber]];
    if ( self.frameNumber == 1 )
    {
        [self.OverPlayPaper addSubview:self.c2cAnimation];
    }
    self.frameNumber = self.frameNumber + 1 ;
}}
```

But when I build and run the app absolutely nothing appears on the screen ...

Do I do any part wrong ? Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all dont alloc any objects multiple times.

You have to write `self.c2cAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 700, 1000)];` just before you start timer.

Second, make sure you have initialize `self.frameNumber = 1;`. if you have not initialize this then write `self.frameNumber = 1;` just before you start timer.

Third, make sure you have start timer properly or use this....

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self selector:@selector(animationTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You will get your desired output

SUMMARY::

```
//START TIMER:

    self.c2cAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 700, 1000)];
    self.frameNumber = 1;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self selector:@selector(animationTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

then write

```
//FUNCTION FOR ANIMATION:

-(void)animationTick
{
     if ( self.frameNumber > 0 && self.frameNumber < 19 )
     {
          self.c2cAnimation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L6_anim_%d.png",self.frameNumber]];
          if ( self.frameNumber == 1 )
          {
               [self.OverPlayPaper addSubview:self.c2cAnimation];
          }
          self.frameNumber = self.frameNumber + 1 ;
     }
}
```